# Android how to get contact list which used whats app application programmatically

Tags: android, whatsapp

i have working with small android application in this application i am try to get contact which used whats app application and also alert for my selected whats app contact from my application when contact updates his/her profile picture and status.

Answer (score 9):

You can query your content cursor to see what properties contacts have.

```
Cursor c1 = appActivity.getContentResolver().query(
                     ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI
                     ,null,null,null, null);
c1.moveToFirst();
DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(c1);
c1.close();
```

Or specifically if you want to query for whatsapp contacts here are the properties:

- You can query for `ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE` with value **com.whatsapp**
- You can use `MIMETYPE` with value **vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.profile**

Example:

```
 c = appActivity.getContentResolver().query(
             ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI
             ,new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.Data._ID }
            ,"mimetype=?",
             new String[] { "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.profile" }, null);

c1.moveToFirst();
DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(c1);
c1.close();
```

Note (@Ragnar): `MIMETYPE` column didn't work for me. I used `ACCOUNT_TYPE` column and it worked.

Comment: `ACCOUNT_TYPE` column worked for me. You saved my day. Thank you.

Comment: @Simon Account_Type column's value  is not same on all devices

Answer (score 2):

If you wish read Telegram contacts:

```
private val tgContactMimeType = "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.org.telegram.messenger.android.profile";

private val projectionTelegram = arrayOf(
    ContactsContract.Data.DATA1,//userId
    ContactsContract.Data.DATA3,//userPhone
    ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME)//displayName

//read telegram contacts
phoneCursor = cr.query(
    ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
    projectionTelegram,
    ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = '" + tgContactMimeType + "'",
    null,
    null)
if (phoneCursor != null) {
    while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
        val userId = phoneCursor.getString(0)
        val number = phoneCursor.getString(1)
        val displayname = phoneCursor.getString(2)
        val contact = PhoneContact()
        contact.firstName = displayname
        contact.phones.add(number)
        contactsMap[userId.toString()] = contact
    }
}
```