# Android Show Contacts that have Telegram account

Tags: android

How to programmatically extract contacts that have telegram account and show in my app?
Contacts that have the telegram account are displayed as shown below.

[image]

Comment: get the account MIME type for telegram

Answer (score 2):

Follow below steps

Get the account MIME type for telegram.

Have the content cursor to query for telegram contacts.

For details on how to do it. check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24227356/android-how-to-get-contact-list-which-used-whats-app-application-programmaticall)